# Remove DataSourceID with code?

Tags: .net, asp.net, linq, datasource

I have a DataList which is bound to a SqlDataSource,
Ive got a LINQ query which the users can use to narrow down the data, I'm making the DataSource = the LINQ on the click event of a button.

I get an error as the list has a DataSourceID and now I'm giving it a DataSource.

Think this would work if i removed the datasourceid first with code before binding to the new LINQ?
If so, any hints on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BaseDataBoundControl`, `BaseDataList`, etc has 2 options how data can be bound to:

- `DataSource` (like LINQ result)
- `DataSourceId` (like SqlDataSource)

Use one of them, or null first before assigning second.